# Version 6.0 (6A313) crashing whenever i try to "Save for enterprise deployment"

Tags: xcode6

Is anyone experiencing this?

Xcode will crash and throw the error below:

```
Process:         Xcode [1208]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         6.0 (6299)
Build Info:      IDEFrameworks-6299000000000000~8
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [227]
Responsible:     Xcode [1208]
User ID:         505

Date/Time:       2014-09-18 11:37:28.745 +0800
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.9.4 (13E28)
Report Version:  11
Anonymous UUID:  A819F892-0B04-883D-E5AC-30EB917E651C

Crashed Thread:  11  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
```

Getting very fustrating.

Comment: I'm getting this as well...

Comment: Hi David,the way i resolved it was to make sure to use the correct account just before you try to export it. 

In previous xcode version, they didnt match the accounts just before you export. Any valid developer account (enterprise or not i am not sure) will suffice. 


Now they do check and they must match before you export.

Now the problem goes away.